# How do I send/receive binary data over TCP using Apache Camel

Tags: tcp, apache-camel

I see numerous examples of using Apache Camel to send or receive data over a TCP connection, as long as the data is **text**. For example setting up an endpoint such as `netty:tcp://localhost:5000?textline=true`. The important thing to note here is the usage of the option `textline=true`. This works great when you are dealing with text, not so much if it's just bytes.

How do I do the same thing, except that instead of text, I'm sending blobs of binary data (*it's not serialized Java objects*)? From what I could find, it would seem that I need to specify a codec to use (instead of the default text codec when `textline=true` is used), but I don't know how to do that.

I can't find any good examples of how to do this either on the Camel site nor anywhere else.

**UPDATE** [Thu Jul 19 10:43:10 EDT 2018]:

I have managed to attain a certain degree of success. I created a simple `DataFormat` and plugged it into the stream:

```
public class ByteArrayFormat implements DataFormat {
  @Override
  public void marshal(Exchange exchange, Object object, OutputStream ostream) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter().mandatoryConvertTo(byte[].class, object);
    ostream.write(bytes);
  }
  @Override
  public Object unmarshal(Exchange exchange, InputStream istream) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter().mandatoryConvertTo(byte[].class, istream);
    return bytes;
  }
}
```

I am not 100% sure this works, as I may have been seeing only unmarshal in action. Any suggestions or corrections are welcome.

I then modified my route as follows:

```
    public void configure() {
      from("netty4:tcp://localhost:5000?allowDefaultCodec=false&sync=false").unmarshal(new ByteArrayFormat())
          .process(processor).to("file://test");
    }
```

The testing "processor" does nothing more than grab the input stream from the exchange and hexdump the data to the console. The "to" just places what it gets in a file so I can look at it there as well.

I then did a simple test where I piped the contents of a binary file (via `nc`) and watched what happened. As far as I can tell, I received the data of the file as bytes.

There is a major caveat though. The result was broken into 1024 byte blocks (which I assume is a limitation imposed by the network stack), so the original file of 3862 bytes came over as four "receives" of 1024 byte blocks (really, 3 x 1024 + 790). Any ideas or suggestions on how to "stitch" this back together would be helpful.

Comment: All data has some meaningful format.  If none of the built-in formats suit you, could you create one of your own?   http://camel.apache.org/custom-dataformat.html

Comment: I don't need to create a format, just get the bytes that were transmitted over the TCP connection. How do I do that?

Comment: I get that, but Apache Camel is not designed to do that.  What you describe can be done without Camel, using an ordinary socket connection.

Comment: OK, let me clarify a bit. I'm trying to write something that could receive data from multiple types of sources (not simultaneously) such as XML over ActiveMQ, or in this case, a proprietary binary format over TCP or UDP. This is why I'm trying to use Camel. I'm trying to take advantage (if I can) of the way Camel simplifies some of the process of sending or receiving information.

Comment: I take it you don't have access to this proprietary data format?

Comment: The simplification that Camel brings to the table is its handling of *structured data formats.*  If what you're sending is not structured in any way, then there's nothing for Camel to do.

Comment: I was able to get the binary data when I set it up to receive over UDP. That was simple.

Comment: Well, it is structured, I just don't know what the structure is.

Comment: Prior to trying to use Camel I had some pretty substantial code that received data from a TCP socket channel and provided the data captured. It had to do a lot of work to account for the possibility of packet fragmentation and the like. It works, but there's a lot of code to do the job. The original problem that I was trying to solve was to capture ActiveMQ OpenWire data format data, modify specific information in the message and then forward it on to its destination. Basically, fuzzing the message. Ran into various problems and was pointed towards Camel as a possible solution.

Comment: In your original problem, you know the data format.

Comment: Yes, but for this case, I do not. I need to grab the wire format byte blob so that I can do more with it. A prior processing step would have been performed that will discover the locations of data within this blob. The algorithm that does the discovery does not attempt to focus on any particular format. It is intended to be agnostic to data formats.

Comment: Please see a related posting that provides more background. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291686/could-apache-camel-help-in-implementing-a-message-fuzzer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176324/discussion-between-joseph-gagnon-and-robert-harvey).

Comment: Hi Joseph Gagnon! Did you solve your problem? I need same functionality